# custom list field design problem

Tags: blackberry, listfield

I have added three custom listfield on a single screen which are separated by some space and labels. I have also drawn a roundrect on each row.
The problem that i am facing is, whenver the first row of each listfield is diaplayed off the screen, the bottom line of round rect of that field also disappears. And this is happening for all the listfields. 
I have also invalidated all the listfields during focus and unfocus but the same problem is occurring.

please suggest something..............

Comment: Would you be able to add the code you're using to paint the rectangle? Or if it isn't too much, the relevant parts of the custom ListField as a whole?

Comment: how did you solve this ? Maybe your solution can help other as well.

Comment: actually i was passing getHeight() in the graphic's drawRoundRect method and that was redrawing the listfield , not the individual rows. previously -- graphics.drawRoundRect(0, y, getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0); So i passed the row height like this -- graphics.drawRoundRect(0, y, getWidth(), getRowHeight(), 0, 0); and that solved my problem :)